# Android TV webview loading

Tags: android, android-tv

I have an android tv 'wrapper' that will load a webapp using webview. It all loads fine using `webview.loadUrl('someurl')` but whilst the page is loading, it's just a grey background.

What I wanted to do was first load a static file - which shows a loading spinner, and then load the main application, but doing this still makes the screen grey whilst the main app is loading.

Is there a simple way to either spin up a second webview ( seems wasteful ) - or to load one url (the file) and then the main remote url?

Comment: Did my answer ever work?

Answer (score 1):

I would have my xml layout like so:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/loadingOrders"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/lato"
        android:text="Loading..." />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pbLoading"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webViewOrders"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

This displays the loading screen and then in the code when the webview is done loading, hide the `LinearLayout`

The code to check the loading is like so:

```
webViewOrders.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, final int newProgress) {

        // UPDATE PROGRESS
        pbLoading.setProgress(newProgress);

        // CHECK IF FULLY LOADED
        if (newProgress == 100) {

            // HIDE VIEW
            findViewById(R.id.loadingOrders).setVisibility(View.GONE);


        }


    }
});
```